# When running gcloud commands I get "ERROR: Reachability Check failed."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have upgraded the `gcloud` version in our CI runners to the latest version, and I now get this error every time I run a `gcloud` command:

```
$ $GCLOUD info --run-diagnostics
Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...
done.
ERROR: Reachability Check failed.
    Cannot reach https://www.google.com (SSLHandshakeError)
    Cannot reach https://accounts.google.com (SSLHandshakeError)
    Cannot reach https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects (SSLHandshakeError)
    Cannot reach https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform (SSLHandshakeError)
    Cannot reach https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json (SSLHandshakeError)
Network connection problems may be due to proxy or firewall settings.
```

It has worked fine before. I'm running this in a debian docker container on GitLab. The `cloudsdk` is downloaded from here `https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz` and the version pinned is: `284.0.0`.

When I run `$GCLOUD config set auth/disable_ssl_validation True` it works. I have looked everywhere online but haven't found anything useful. Some people suggested adding something to the `cacerts.txt` file, but I haven't found anything that worked.

Comment: Can you check if traffic on port 443 is allowed? not blocked by firewall rules?

Comment: Traffic to 443 https servers is allowed. `openssl s_client -connect stackoverflow.com:443` works

Comment: This is not a firewall issue. This problem looks like a PROXY issue. The point that you can get past this with `config set auth/disable_ssl_validation` means that it is a CA certificate issue. However, I don't know the solution. Locate where `gcloud` is installed: `which gcloud`. Then from that directory check the `cacert.pem` files to make sure they are current. Also look at `custom_ca_certs_file`: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set

Comment: How did you upgrade the `gcloud` tool? Using https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update?

Comment: @Juancki No we simply downloaded the latest sdk and pinned the most recent version. We're seeing this issue in our CI runners.

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile / compose.yaml?

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: @wonsuc nope. Running without ssl validation for over a year now.

Comment: Thank you, I actually fixed this with FM solution.